# Laravel Paginate by column value

Tags: php, sql, laravel, pagination, query-builder

I would like to find out if the following is possible with laravel query builder. Currently using Laravel 9.

I want to create pagination, but instead if supplying the count
`->paginate(20)` as per example, I would like to paginate according to column value.

To give more detail on what I want each page to display, let me provider example.

We have table with 4 column, column a(id, auto increment), b(fruit_type), c(supplier) and d(quantity)

Column a and b contains result set as follows (Column c and d have no purpose other than giving a better description)

```
1   apple
2   apple
3   apple
4   apple
5   apple
6   pear
7   pear
8   pear
9   pear
10  pear
11  pear
12  pear
```

So there are 7 results for pear and 5 for apple and I only want each pagination page to display one type of fruit. So page 1 will only have apples and page 2 pears, page 3 different fruit type etc.

I'm unaware of how to get this done.

So essentially this will be creating dynamic range according to column value.

So we want a query something like this, however

```
DB::table('Fruit')->where('something', '=', 'something')
->orderBy('fruit_type')->groupBy('id', 'fruit_type')
->paginate('this value will need to be dynamic as each fruit type count varies');
```

Your assistance will be greatly appreciated

Comment: could be there a case, when for example you have 10 apple records, 100 pear records and 1 peach reacord?? so i just will understand, do you wanna have a pagination with 3 pages, where you'll have 10 apple items on the first page, 100 pear items on the second page and 1 peach item on the third page. Is this correct ??

Comment: i think you misunderstood pagination, pagination is nothing other than limit and offset, so you can't  set it dynamically for one query. you can only loop through the resultset and set a new page

Answer (score 0):

As @nbk already mentioned, pagination is purely limiting and offset. However, you *can* build your own "paginator".

In your controller:

```php
// Get available fruits
$fruits = DB::table('Fruit')->select('fruit_type')
    ->distinct()
    ->pluck('fruit_type')
    ->toArray();

// Get current fruit or default to first result
$currentFruit = $request->input('fruit_type', Arr::first($fruits));

$results = DB::table('Fruit')->where('fruit_type', $currentFruit)->get();

return view("your-view", compact('fruits', 'currentFruit', 'results');
```

Then, in your view:

```html
@foreach($results as $result)
    {{-- Display your results as you wish --}}
    {{ $result->id }}
@endforeach

@foreach($fruitTypes as $fruitType)
    @php $isActive = $fruitType === $currentFruit; @endphp
    <a href="{{ route('your-controller-route-name', ['fruit_type' => $fruitType]) }}" class="@if($isActive) active @endif">
        {{ $fruitType }}
    </a>
@endforeach
```

This is obviously just a simple variant, you can make it as complex as you want it to be.